# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I keep getting these errors, but can't seem to realize why. I'm new to oracle sql, so any help would be welcome! thanks in advance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGER1 AFTER DELETE OR INSERT ON LAB6_BILETI 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  CNT NUMBER;
  CNP NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 WHERE T1.T=:OLD.T INTO CNT

  IF CNT=0 THEN
    UPDATE T2 SET VP=1 WHERE T2.T=:old.T;
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 WHERE T1.T=:old.T AND T1.P=:old.P INTO CNP;

  IF CNP=0 AND CNT!=0 THEN
    UPDATE T2 SET VK=VK+1 WHERE T2.T=:old.T;
  END IF;

END;
```

Errors:

> Compilation failed, line 6 (16:27:48)
>   The line numbers associated with
>   compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This
>   only affects the compilation of database triggers.
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   Compilation failed, line 5 (16:27:48)
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignoredCompilation failed, line 7 (16:27:48)
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly endedCompilation failed, line 7 (16:27:48)
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Compilation failed, line 11 (16:27:48)
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted
>   delimited-identifier>

Comment: You should take `INTO CNP` just after `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: Same thing for `INTO CNT`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I just did, I still get the errors :/

Comment: Try with my change as well

Comment: @JoakimDanielson same thing, errors still present .

Comment: By the way, I don't know what tool you are using, but the line numbers associated with trigger compilation errors are relative to the first `begin` **or** `declare`. In this case it is referring to the keywords being in the wrong order in the line `select count(*) from xxx into yyy`, which should be `select count(*) into yyy from xxx` as @BarbarosÖzhan mentioned.

Comment: What is that `'enter code here'` supposed to be?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  T2.T=:old.T, it was a typo

Comment: Well, with the `select x into y` keywords in the right order and the typo removed it should compile successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted trigger code has several syntax errors and some logic errors too.

The syntax errors are

- in regular PL/SQL the INTO clause comes directly after the SELECT projection and before the FROM clause.
- there is a missing semicolon after the first SELECT statement.

The logical flaw is that for INSERT triggers the `:old` namespace is blank, so the selected counts will always be zero and the updates will miss. (Perhaps that is what you intended, but if so you should comment your code to that effect.) Changing this is not as simple as substituting the `:new` namespace because that will be blank when DELETING.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGER1 AFTER DELETE OR INSERT ON LAB6_BILETI 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  CNT NUMBER;
  CNP NUMBER;
  l_t t1.t%type;
  l_p t1.p%type;
BEGIN

 if deleting then 
     l_t := :OLD.T ;
     l_p := :OLD.P ;
 else -- inserting
     l_t := :NEW.T ;
     l_p := :NEW.P ;
 end if;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT
  FROM T1 
  WHERE T1.T= l_t ;

  IF CNT=0 THEN
    UPDATE T2 
    SET VP=1 
    WHERE T2.T= l_t;
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*)  INTO CNP
  FROM T1
  WHERE T1.T= l_t
  AND T1.P= l_p;

  IF CNP=0 AND CNT!=0 THEN
    UPDATE T2 
    SET VK=VK+1 
    WHERE T2.T= l_t;
  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you, you even helped me solve a problem I didn't know I had !